# Flutter: Overput image over image save it on image and then share it

Tags: image, flutter, camera, photo

I want to add a simple image over an image from the gallery/camera. The behavior should be like it.

Open the application, choose a photo or make one with the floating buttons, then show the image and over put our logo on the bottom left. All it is working now.

Then I would like to save it both images in a single one, but I don't know how this process is called or how to achieve it.

```
import 'package:share/share.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image Picker Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Image Picker Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _imageFile;
  dynamic _pickImageError;
  String _retrieveDataError;

  void _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      _imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    } catch (e) {
      _pickImageError = e;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _previewImage() {
    final Text retrieveError = _getRetrieveErrorWidget();
    if (retrieveError != null) {
      return retrieveError;
    }
    if (_imageFile != null) {
      print('La imagen ha sido puesta en la pantalla?');
      return Image.file(_imageFile);
    } else if (_pickImageError != null) {
      return Text(
        'Pick image error: $_pickImageError',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    } else {
      return const Text(
        'You have not yet picked an image.',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
    final LostDataResponse response = await ImagePicker.retrieveLostData();
    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    if (response.file != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = response.file;
      });
    } else {
      _retrieveDataError = response.exception.code;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Platform.isAndroid
                ? FutureBuilder<void>(
                    future: retrieveLostData(),
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return const Text(
                            'You have not yet picked an image.',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          );
                        case ConnectionState.done:
                          return _previewImage();
                        default:
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text(
                              'Pick image/video error: ${snapshot.error}}',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            );
                          } else {
                            return const Text(
                              'You have not yet picked an image.',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            );
                          }
                      }
                    },
                  )
                : (_previewImage())), //
        Positioned(
            bottom: 16,
            left: 16,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Image.network(
                'http://father-home.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cropped-logo8.png'))
      ]))),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource.gallery);
            },
            heroTag: 'image0',
            tooltip: 'Pick Image from gallery',
            child: const Icon(Icons.photo_library),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource.camera);
              },
              heroTag: 'image1',
              tooltip: 'Take a Photo',
              child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _onShare();
              },
              tooltip: 'Share',
              child: const Icon(Icons.share),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onShare(){

//TODO: save the two images into one and share

  }

  Text _getRetrieveErrorWidget() {
    if (_retrieveDataError != null) {
      final Text result = Text(_retrieveDataError);
      _retrieveDataError = null;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

the widget with this code looks like it:

[image: the current state of the widget]

Comment: Any luck with this? I need the same functionality and I am wondering if you have a solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **RepaintBoundary** widget to export a specific widget to image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will need to work with Bitmap.

1. Load 2 bitmaps, one is the background, one is your logo.
2. Apply transformation as you like.
3. Save output bitmap to file.

Take a look at: https://pub.dev/packages/bitmap